# Ajax request to edit fields mvc

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, razor

I'm using mvc 4, I would like to make an item fields editable by simply clicking on the Edit link. I want the fields to change into editable text boxes without a full post back. Unfortunately the editable fields appear on a blank page.
Here is the Index view:

```
    [HttpGet]
    public ActionResult Edit(int id)
    {
        Item it = Items.Find(i=> i.ItemId == id);
        return PartialView("_Editor", it);

    }
    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult Edit(Item item)
    {
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            Item it = Items.Find(i => i.ItemId == item.ItemId);
            it.ItemName = item.ItemName;
            it.ItemCategory = item.ItemCategory;
            it.ItemDescription = item.ItemDescription;
            it.ItemPrice = item.ItemPrice;
            return RedirectToAction("Index");
        }
        return HttpNotFound();
    }

    //
    // GET: /Restaurant/
    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        var model = Items;
        return View(model);
    }
```

Here is the Index view:

```
    @model IEnumerable<RestoItemTes.Models.Item>

    @{
    }

    @foreach (var item in Model)
    {
        Html.RenderPartial("_Reader", item);

        @:<br style="clear: both;" />
    }
```

Partial view _Reader:

```
    @model RestoItemTes.Models.Item

    <div id="@Model.ItemId" style="border: 1px solid #777; margin: 5px auto; width: 50%;">
        <div class="name">
            @Html.DisplayFor(m => m.ItemName)
            <span class="category">@Html.DisplayFor(m => m.ItemCategory)</span>
        </div>
        <p class="editor-multiline-field">@Html.DisplayFor(m => m.ItemDescription)</p>
            <span class="price">$ @Html.DisplayFor(m => m.ItemPrice)</span>
            <br />
        <p>
        @Ajax.ActionLink("Edit", "Edit", "Restaurant", new { id = @Model.ItemId },
                                                   new AjaxOptions
                                                    {
                                                        UpdateTargetId = @Model.ItemId.ToString()
                                                    }) |

        @Html.ActionLink("Delete", "Delete", new { id = @Model.ItemId })
       </p>
    </div>
```

And the Editor view:

```
    @model RestoItemTes.Models.Item

    @using (Html.BeginForm("Edit", "Restaurant", FormMethod.Post,
                new AjaxOptions
                {
                    InsertionMode = InsertionMode.Replace,
                    HttpMethod = "POST",
                    UpdateTargetId = @Model.ItemId.ToString()
                }))
    {
        <div class="name">
           @Html.EditorFor(m => m.ItemName)
           <span class="category">@Html.EditorFor(m => m.ItemCategory)</span>
        </div>
        <p class="editor-multiline-field">@Html.EditorFor(m => m.ItemDescription)</p>
        <span class="price">$ @Html.EditorFor(m => m.ItemPrice)</span>
        <br />
        <input type="submit" value="Save" />

    }
```

Any suggestions or comments would be appreciated.
P

Comment: Just checking - have you looked at [jquery client side inline edit plugins](https://www.google.com/search?q=jquery+inline+edit)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can set the class attribute to "editTextBox" and then in your js file Ready method, you can use following code:

```
$('.editTextBox').click(function(){
    $(this).hide();
    $(this).prev().hide();
    $(this).next().show();
    $(this).next().select();
});
```

I found this code here :

> http://www.tonylea.com/2010/jquery-easy-editable-text-fields/

Hope this helps.

Comment: Not secure. A better approach is to have only ONE type of template. The answer does solve the given case. But I mean you'd better return proper model so you could conditionally select between rendering display or editor templates.